# How to open a web page at the end of installation using visual studio C ++ deployment?

Tags: visual-studio-2010, visual-studio, visual-c++, installation, setup-project

Is there any way in visual studio 2010 C++ setup deployment to open a webpage at the end of installation?

I can do this with Inno Setup, but I don't want to be in trouble with another setup.

I simply want to link a webpage in Visual Studio Setup Deployment that should execute after the installation get done.

Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't edit the existing dialogs in a VS setup project, so I suspect you need a custom action (program) that does an "open" on the URL, and that will launch the appropriate browser. You probably need to make that asynchronous because installs generated by VS setups wait for the custom action to finish, so be sure to finish the program.

Comment: Thanks. But it doesn't seem to be an easy way... looks complex when I tried to google it.

Comment: It's just code, and if you search how to do a shell open or ShellExecute on a URL you should find some.